# SQL*Plus how to execute multiple queries in single line?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

In SQL*Plus, I want to execute multiple SQL queries in single line like

```
create table emp(name varchar2(20)); desc emp;
```

I tried executing this one but didn't work for me.

```
BEGIN OPEN :1 FOR SELECT * FROM table1; OPEN :2 FOR SELECT * FROM table2; END;
```

is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are :1 and :2 ?.  Why do u use bind variables for them?

Comment: `desc emp` is NOT a SQL query, it is a SQL\*Plus command (which SQL\*Plus translates, behind the scenes - invisible to you! - into an actual SQL query against several data dictionary tables). Technically there should be no semicolon after `desc emp` although SQL\*Plus may be flexible and not throw an error. Then, your second line of code is not a SQL query either, it is a PL/SQL block. It seems that you have very, very basic understanding issues; go back to the first 15-20 pages of your textbook and re-read about SQL vs. PL/SQL vs. SQL\*Plus, they are very different things.

Comment: @mathguy 
what if I want to execute 
`insert into emp (name) values('Foo')` and 'select * from emp`
in a single line is this possible?
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL*Plus expects either:

- A **single** SQL command, terminated by either a "`;`" character or a "`/`" on a line by itself.
- A PL/SQL block
- A SQL*Plus command

What you have entered is 2 queries on a single line, which SQL*Plus will send to the RDBMS - Oracle will then try and parse the string sent as a single query and fail because it is not valid SQL.

A quick workaround would be to have all your commands in a sql file and run them using `@file.sql`